# default error pages with angular2

Tags: angular

I'd like to have a default error page my application. to achieve that, I implemented an error handler:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  router: Router;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { 
    this.router = this.injector.get(Router);
  }

  handleError(error) {
    this.router.navigate(['error']);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

and create error-page component and route as well:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RecipeListComponent },
  ...
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent }
];
```

but this line, at error hadler does not work... someone have some idea about why?

```
this.router.navigate(['error']);
```

I mean, I'm receiving the error but I'm not able to route to my error page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes with an empty path `''` and without child routes need `pathMatch: 'full'`

```
{ path: '', component: RecipeListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Also a leading `/` ensures the navigation works in all cases

```
this.router.navigate(['/error']);
```